# Does WeakReference.Target.GetType fail if null

Tags: c#

If I am using WeakReference and have initialized it with an object, which then goes null and is GC'd. Will `WeakReference.Target.GetType();` fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will fail with a `NullReferenceException`, because `GetType` is an instance method and `WeakReference.Target` is `null` if the object has been garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks, I will green tick when time allows.

Comment: Are you sure ? The Target property will not become null, only because object becomes null. It *may* become null if object *was collected by GC*. In fact, this is  a known problem with WeakReference that you have to setup some kind of manual GC.

Comment: @Tigran: Please read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.target.aspx): "null if the object referenced by the current WeakReference object has been garbage collected"

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: exactly. But OP's is aksing about simple "goes null". This does not mean that object is already GC collected.

Comment: @Tigran: Setting an object to `null` doesn't make it get garbage collected, that's right. I interpreted "which then goes null" as the object being garbage collected, because this sentence is not clear. An object doesn't "go null". It is being set to null.

Comment: @McDonnellDean: Please see the discussion between Tigran an me. Please clarify what you actually meant, best with an update to your question that contains some illustrating code.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I would mean when it is GC'd.

Comment: @Tigran: Looks like my interpretation - along with the answer - was correct.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: yes I saw it, and actually +1. But will leave mine too, as another point of view on the same subject.

Comment: @Tigran: Yes, with the addition you added to your answer I now like it and +1'd

Answer (score 3):

No, as this is almost the same like :

```
var a = b; 
b = null;     

//a is not null;
```

So your `WeakReference` object continue pointing to the instance of the object that has became `null`. According to the documentation :

> null if the object referenced by the current WeakReference object has
>   been garbage collected; otherwise, a reference to the object
>   referenced by the current WeakReference object.

So untill your object **is not** `GC` collected, you still can use `GetType()` . This done in that way, so you can understand when `WeakReference` referenced object is collected by `GC`.

Comment: This would be flaky though right? Simply because without manual garbage enforcement you could not depend GetType() being available. Gave an uptick though as it looks to be correct.

Comment: @McDonnellDean: if you all GetType() and it raises an exception, you know that object you were referencing before, had already been collected by GC, if not it *may* be null too.

Comment: @McDonnellDean: You would need to check anyway: `if(weakRef.IsAlive) /* save to call weakRef.Target.GetType() */`